# apt cache update keeps failing in sensible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

This is the content of my ansible playbook, I am tying to install php8.1 using the ppa:ondrej/php repo. I keep getting this error

```
fatal: [debian-machine]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "apt cache update failed"}
```

The playbook is to deploy a laravel app but I need to install my PHP8.1 first before moving to the app deployment. This is my playbook below.

```
---
- name: A playbook for laravel deployment
  hosts: laravelserver
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  vars:
          password: "*******"
          ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
  tasks:
          - name: Update and Upgrade apt repository
            apt:
                    upgrade: yes
                    update_cache: yes
                    cache_valid_time: 86400
          - name: Installation of Apache Server
            apt:
                    name: apache2
                    state: present
          - name: Enabling Apache Service
            service:
                    name: apache2
                    enabled: yes
          - name: Installing PHP dependencies
            apt:
                    name:
                            - ca-certificates
                            - apt-transport-https
                            - software-properties-common
                    state: present

          - name: Adding Deb Sury Repo
            apt_repository:
                    repo: ppa:ondrej/php
                    state: present

          - name: Update and Upgrade apt repository
            apt:
                    update_cache: yes

          - name: Installation of PHP8.1 and its dependencies
            apt:
                    name:
                            - php8.1
                            - php8.1-mysql
                            - libapache2-mod-php
                            - php8.1-imap
                            - php8.1-ldap
                            - php8.1-xml
                            - php8.1-fpm
                            - php8.1-curl
                            - php8.1-mbstring
                            - php8.1-zip
                    state: present
```

Please how can I stop this error from displaying when I run the playbook.

Comment: Are the indexes for apt ok? An invalid repository or an expired key will prevent the update of the cache and send such a cryptic error message; to troubleshoot, execute the playbook with `-vvv` or SSH into the affected host and verify that `sudo apt-get update` is able to complete successfully.

Comment: Also note that you are exposing your IP address and password in clear in your post, that is a huge security breach

Comment: I did run sudo apt-get update in my slave machine and I got no error. On running ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i project_host.txt -vvv I got this error 

fatal: [debian-machine]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "codename": null,
            "filename": null,
            "install_python_apt": true,
            "mode": null,
            "repo": "ppa:ondrej/php",
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": true,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "apt cache update failed"
}

Comment: Have you looked in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30754 ? they are reporting a similar error, and some of their experiences of how they solved it

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas the password is an issue; the non-routable, private IP address not so much ... `whois 192.168.56.19` ;)

Comment: `become: yes` followed by `remote_user: root` does not make any sense (unless you also set `become_user` to something else than `root` which would still be awkward in most situations....).